# JSON.Net освобождение jObect ресурсов

Tags: c#, json, парсер, json.net

Есть небольшой код (парсер), берет JSON из вывода web-сервера. Использую так:

```
string HTMLOutput = "Тут полученный JSON код";
dynamic JSONOutput = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(HTMLOutput);
```

JSON достаточно объемный, после десериализации съедает несколько гигов RAM. Как можно освободить ресурсы? Пробовал JSONOutput.Finzlize(); но компилятор ругается.
Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы минимизировать использование памяти и количество выделенных объектов, Json.NET поддерживает сериализацию и десериализацию непосредственно в потоке.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

using (Stream s = client.GetStreamAsync("http://site.com/large.json").Result)
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
     JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

     // Чтение JSON из потока. Размер JSON не имеет значения, 
     // потому что только небольшая часть считывается из HTTP-запроса.
     Person p = serializer.Deserialize<Person>(reader);
}
```